# Odd Python Behavior - Simple Arithmetic

Tags: python

In Python I did `3.08 - 4.31` and got back `-1.2299999999999995`.

This is definitely not right (`-1.23` is right) and highly concerning. I am not seeing this behavior in other languages, any insights into what Python is doing here?

Comment: Any language that uses floating point will be prone to this same problem.  Whether you're actually noticing it or not could be due to a number of factors, but you are guaranteed the problem exists and will be visible under certain circumstances.

Comment: You may be interested in the `decimal` module...

Answer (score 1):

You can find a great explanation here:
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

To fix this use `round(3.08 - 4.31, 2)`